# While resolving: react-spinners@0.9.0 (old React project)

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a React app which I haven't worked on in awhile. After cloning I run `npm i` and get the following errors:

```
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! While resolving: react-spinners@0.9.0 npm ERR! Found:
> react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1"
> from the root project npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from
> @emotion/core@10.1.1 npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/core npm ERR!   
> @emotion/core@"^10.0.15" from react-spinners@0.9.0 npm ERR!    
> node_modules/react-spinners npm ERR!       react-spinners@"^0.9.0"
> from the root project npm ERR!   8 more (@testing-library/react,
> mini-create-react-context, ...) npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not resolve
> dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-spinners@0.9.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-spinners npm ERR!  
> react-spinners@"^0.9.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-spinners@0.9.0 npm ERR!  
> node_modules/react-spinners npm ERR!     react-spinners@"^0.9.0" from
> the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency
> conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or
> --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!  npm ERR! See
> /home/arch/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> /home/arch/.npm/_logs/2023-02-01T09_41_23_592Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can fix this and what the best practice would be to update my dependencies with little headache.

Comment: `react-spinners` version `0.9.0` only support react 16. You need to update `react-spinners` to version `0.13.8` using `npm i react-spinners@0.13.8`. If you don't want to update it you can run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Could you make this an answer so I can mark it solved? Thank you.

Also How did you find which version it needed?

Comment: It's the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-spinners` version `0.9.0` only support react 16.

You need to update `react-spinners` to version `0.13.8`. *version `0.13.8` Is today newest version*

Run `npm i react-spinners@0.13.8`.

If you don't want to update it you can run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` when you install node_modules